# Is moment of inertia 0 in bodies rotating on its own axis?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

As we know, 
$I=mr^2$ 
where r is the perpendicular distance between axis of rotation and centre of mass.
if r is 0 then moment of inertia is also zero.
I didn't understand this. If anyone has some idea about this topic then could you please answer my question.

Comment: $I=\sum_i m_i r_i^2$. Check out the wikipedia page.

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE :) It would help if you edited your post to explain _why_ you do not understand this (or in which way you _expect_ to understand this)

Comment: As mentioned in the top comment, the point in moment of inertia is to *sum  together all contributions*. Remember the sum sign. Correctly, the particles in the axis make no difference, since $r$ is zero, but all others have nonzero distance and add up. Only if you try to find the moment of inertia of something like a point (or point-like particle or so) can the moment of inertia be zero. Otherwise you will always have some extend in all 3 dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Your perception that $I=mr^2$ is itself misleading. The actual calculation of moment of inertia stems from $I=\iiint r^2\, dm$. The definition you use is valid only for a particle mass. So, for a particle spinning about itself, yes $I$=0.

Comment: ... and for an extended rigid body, no.

Comment: why not for an extended rigid body?

Comment: If there is mass at a location away from the origin $\| {\bf r} \|>0$ then $I>0$

Comment: when I said, particle spinning about itself, I meant a dot spinning about an axis passing through the dot, hence I used the word 'itself'. In this case, $I=0$

Comment: I agree. But I think you need to state the contrary that when not a dot, but an extended body, it is not.